# Using Throughput shaping timer

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I want to know how I can use throughout shaping timer in jmeter. I have 5 api's which I need to run one after the other
 I don't think creating separate thread for each request would work. Please let me know how I can use throughput shaping timer plugin to achieve TPS associated with each api request.

Answer (score 0):

[Throughout shaping timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer) is used to achieve target rate (Request Per Second).Its used to schedule RPS Load

You can mention TPS associated with each api, add a throughput shaping timer as a child of api call and schedule your RPS load, give enough number of threads to achieve your RPS load..
I just executed a dummy test with different RPS for different samplers refer to the screenshot below

1st Sampler RPS schedule
[image]

2nd Sampler RPS schedule
[image]

RPS result at the end of test
[image]

To know about throughput shaping timer please read this article which explains the [usage of throughput shaping timer](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/07/throughput-shaping-timer/)